# Existe uma forma de executar um comando interno armazenado em um arquivo .txt (ou em String) no Delphi?

Tags: string, delphi, texto, comandos

Estou tentando exibir uma imagem  ao carregar um Form, mas o comando precisa vir de um arquivo externo .txt (ou de uma string que vai armazenar esse comando existente no .txt).
Eu consigo mostrar as linhas com ShowMessage, dessa forma:

```
procedure TFrmAlbum.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
var
Achar : TStringList;
j : Integer;
img : String;
begin
             Achar := TStringList.Create;
             Try
               Achar.LoadFromFile('images.txt');
               for j := 0 to Achar.Count-1 do
                 begin
                   ShowMessage(Achar[j]);
                 end;
             Finally
             Achar.Free;
             End;
end;
```

O que quero é algum comando que possa usar no lugar do **ShowMessage** para em vez de mostrar as linhas, executá-las. Será que tem como fazer isso?

**Edit1:**
Não sei se vai ajudar, mas as linhas de comando que estão no .txt, que devem ser interpretadas pelo programa são como essas:

```
Image1.Picture.Bitmap.LoadFromResourceName(HInstance, 'Bitmap_1');
Image2.Picture.Bitmap.LoadFromResourceName(HInstance, 'Bitmap_2');
```

Comment: Executar um código de um arquivo externo? Acho meio difícil uma vez que o Delphi é compilado e não interpretado.

Comment: No caso, você quer que o próprio sistema operacional execute o comando (abrindo a imagem no programa padrão)? Você pode utilizar o comando ShellExecute (uses ShellApi).

Comment: @Jhonny Freire, pesquisei a respeito e vi que uma solução seria criar um interpretador (acho que de pascal), mas é complicado, principalmente para mim que sou iniciante (e autodidata) em Delphi. Estou procurando uma forma de contornar isso, só não sei se é possível...

Comment: @Ricardo Alves Carvalho, o que quero é que o programa que estou fazendo execute o comando (mostrar uma imagem no TImage), não o Sistema Operacional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estou supondo que cada linha do arquivo ficará em um TImage nomeado Image1, Image2, etc. Também estou supondo que os arquivos são todos bitmaps.

`procedure TFrmAlbum.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
  var
    Achar : TStringList;
    i, j : Integer;
  begin
    Achar := TStringList.Create;
    Try
      Achar.LoadFromFile('images.txt');
      for j := 0 to Achar.Count-1 do
      begin
        i := pos('_', Achar[j]) + 1;
        i := StrToInt(copy(Achar[j], i, 10));
        TImage(FindComponent(
          'Image' + IntToStr(i))).Picture.Bitmap.LoadFromResourceName(HInstance, Achar[j]);
      end;
    Finally
      Achar.Free;
    End;
  end;`

Comment: Ricardo Alves Carvalho está correto em suas suposições. Mas ainda não teve o resultado esperado. Ao executar, recebo a mensagem:
'Unknown picture file extension
(.LoadFromResourceName(HInstance, 'Bitmap_1');)'
Parece que pegou parte do comando em vez de pegar a linha toda.

Comment: Vc quer ler de recurso ou de arquivo? O código acima é pra ler de arquivo bitmap. O images.txt teria o nome completo de um arquivo por linha.

Comment: As imagens estão armazenadas no executável, então a leitura é de recursos, como está salvo no arquivo.txt (veja o Edit1 que acrescentei na pergunta). Estou tentando colocar o caminho que resta no começo do seu código (o que recebo como resposta), mas encontrando o erro 'Incompatible types' porque estou usando uma String pra isso. O que deveria usar nesse caso?

Comment: O que fiz: Declarei variável img como string (tentei ShortString tb devido a msg de erro apresentada com String)

 ```               img :=  'Image' + IntToStr(j + 1) +'.Picture.Bitmap';
               img+ TImage(FindComponent('Image' + IntToStr(j + 1))).Picture.LoadFromFile(Achar[j]);
```

Comment: O trecho dentro loop: TImage(FindComponent('Image' + IntToStr(j))).Picture.Bitmap.LoadFromResourceName(HInstance, Achar[j]); //aqui, as linhas do arquivo deverão ter o nome do recurso.

Comment: Quando uso desse jeito, recebo a msg "Access violation at address 00635FCD in moidule 'Project_Teste.exe'. Read of address 000001D0."

Comment: Coloquei um 'Application.ProcessMessages;' antes de carregar o TImage, e o erro passou a ser "List index out of bounds (2)" e tb tenho a msg do delphi "[dcc32 Warning] Teste.pas(179): W1037 FOR-Loop variable 'j' may be undefined after loop". Dei uma pesquisada e pelo que entendi é algum parâmetro que está errado, mas não consegui achar qual.

Comment: Cometi um erro onde pus o código do loop, onde está "IntToStr(j)))", deveria ser "IntToStr(j) + 1))". Isso é para casar o "Image1" com a linha "0" do stringList. Também é importante que você não leia mais linhas do arquivo do que o número de TImages que existam em seu Form. Agora, esta mensagem do j estar indefinido após o loop indica que o seu código não está conforme o exemplo. Verifique se o comando dentro do loop tem mais de uma linha e, se for o caso, use begin..end para delimitar o bloco.

Comment: Ricardo Alves Carvalho, quase lá... Seu código está perfeito, mas o programa não está encontrado a imagem. Agora recebo a mensagem: 
"Resource Image1.Picture.Bitmap.LoadFromResourceName(HInstance, 'Bitmap_1'); not found"'.
Detalhe, funciona quando uso o código:
```
begin
     if (FindComponent('Image' +IntToStr(a)) as TImage).Picture.height = 0 then
     (FindComponent('Image' +IntToStr(a)) as TImage).Picture.Bitmap.LoadFromResourceName(HInstance, 'Bitmap_' +IntToStr(a));
end;
```
É o mesmo endereço de imagem, o que será que tá faltando?

Comment: Complementando, o código está no OnShow do Form principal e dando a msg acima. Agora se tiro do OnShow e coloco ele no OnChange de um ComboBox, o erro volta a ser "Access violation at address 006A6452 in module 'Project_Teste.exe'. Read of address 000001D0." quando acessa o arquivo .txt (fiz o teste e se o arquivo estiver vazio não acontece nada). Se o comando é o mesmo, por que erros diferentes?

Comment: Mais uma observação, o ComboBox onde coloquei o comando está em outro Form, talvez seja esse o motivo do erro "Access violation" em vez "Resource ... not found". Se for isso, tem como eu indicar que o resultado deve ser aplicado no Form principal? Só adicionar o nome do Form na frente do "TImage(FindComponent..." com ponto ou com parênteses não funcionou...

Comment: FormPrincipal.FindComponent

Comment: Foi  mesmo falta de atenção minha, e de pensar um pouco mais... Agora o erro é o mesmo de antes, "Resource... not found". Vi várias pessoas reclamando disso, mas não achei nenhuma solução, todos dizem que o motivo é pelo compilador do Delphi não encontrar o arquivo, mas ele abre a imagem usando o exemplo que dei numa das respostas anteriores.

Comment: Você tem que fazer a inclusão do arquivo de recursos na mesma unit onde o está carregando. Considerando que você está fazendo chamadas de um form para outro, verifique se o exemplo que funcionava não está em outra unit.

Comment: Incluí os arquivos pelo "Resources and images..." de "Project" (estava no Form principal quando fiz, mas acho que serve pra qualquer Form do Projeto). De qualquer maneira, o erro de "Resource... not found" acontece tanto da chamada do Form principal, como do secundário. Criei um botão de teste no Form principal pra ver as possibilidades de solução (até agora não consegui nada) e a chamada pelo botão dá o mesmo erro. Já se coloco o comando direto, sem usar seu código, aí a imagem é carregada.

Comment: Acho que pra entender o problema preciso ver o código. Se isso não for um problema, poste aqui ou envie para ricardo.alves.carvalho@gmail.com.

Comment: O Google não deixa enviar os arquivos, mas usei o serviço do wetransfer para enviar para você. Deve chegar um link no seu e-mail. Não é problema divulgar o código aqui, mas como ele está cheio de comentários e comandos que uso para testes, ficaria muito trabalhoso limpar isso antes de postar.

Comment: Nelson, o comando do loop é: "TImage(FindComponent('Image' + IntToStr(j+1))).Picture.Bitmap.LoadFromResourceName(HInstance, Achar[j]);". Achar[i] deveria ter um conteúdo como "Bitmap_5", por exemplo, mas o arquivo que carrega o StringList está populado com linhas do tipo: "Image5.Picture.Bitmap.LoadFromResourceName(HInstance, 'Bitmap_5');". Os comandos devem ficar no seu programa; o arquivo deve ter apenas o conteúdo variável que possa ser carregado como string. Altere o arquivo, e teste, vamos ver se dará certo.

Comment: Sim, agora ele lê a imagem, mas carrega nos TImage na ordem em que aparecem e não no correspondente àquela imagem. Se no txt tenho "Bitmap_5" e "Bitmap_6", por exemplo, ele deveria abrir no "Image5" e "Image6", mas tá carregando nos "Image1" e "Image2", respectivamente.

Comment: Achei que era esse o objetivo. Não é difícil adaptar, vou alterar o código da minha resposta acima.

Comment: Não é difícil pra quem sabe, rsrs. Estou tentando e não saio do lugar. A opção FindComponent já deveria fazer essa associação, não consigo entender porque encontra a imagem e não associa ao Image correspondente.

Comment: Parece que falta pouco agora, mas ainda não foi... A mensagem de erro é "There is no overloaded version of 'Pos' that can be called with these arguments". Não entendi também aquele "10" que colocou no segundo valor do i ( i := StrToInt(copy(Achar[j], i, **10**));), qual a função dele?

Comment: Se peço pra ignorar (fiz só pra testar) a linha de busca por '_', o programa compila, mas dá erro ao carregar a imagem, dizendo que não é um valor inteiro válido.

Comment: Tem um "img : String;" na variável que não usou tb, tentei ver onde se encaixaria mas não deu certo em lugar nenhum...

Comment: Acho que achei o significado do **10** na expressão, é até onde a cópia deve ser feita... mas nada sobre o erro do Pos...

Comment: Foi erro meu. O pos deveria ser "Pos('_', Achar[j]);", vou editar a resposta. O comando copy tem 3 parâmetros, a string a copiar, a posição a partir da qual a cópia inicia e a quantidade de caracteres a copiar. Quando passamos o 3º parâmetro com mais caracteres do que há na string disponíveis para cópia, o comando retorna apenas os caracteres disponíveis. Então, passando 10, na prática, o comando copia a string da posição seguinte ao underline até o fim da string. O problema é que estou fazendo de cabeça, sem compilar para checar se tem erros.

Comment: Removi a variavel img. Tinha colocado para fazer dois comandos que acabei concatenando: TImage(FindComponent(
          'Image' + IntToStr(i))).Picture.LoadFromFile(Achar[j]);  -> poderia ser: 1) img := TImage(FindComponent(
          'Image' + IntToStr(i))); 2) img.Picture.LoadFromFile(Achar[j]);

Comment: Já tinha pesquisado sobre o copy, eu tava usando, mas sem saber direito o que fazia...
Bom, agora tá compilando, mas não carrega as imagens. Mais a noite vejo direito, porque agora to trabalhando e não consigo me dedicar a isso.

Comment: Achei a solução, foi só trocar a última chamada para ```(TImage(FindComponent('Image' + IntToStr(i))).Picture.Bitmap.LoadFromResourceName(HInstance, Achar[j]) );``` Agradeço muito pela paciência, pela ajuda e pelo conhecimento adquirido. Vou aguardar editar sua resposta para dar como Aceita.

Comment: Isso mesmo, na pressa acabei esquecendo do resource, kkkk. Melhor ainda que você achou.